# How to define a function that output another function?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I want to define a function that takes some arguments as input, and uses them to make another function, then outputs the new function.

For example:

makeIncrease(n) --> return a function that takes an argument, and return (argument + n)

applyIncrease(increaseFn, m) --> will apply increaseFn to argument m

So if I do this: applyIncrease(makeIncrease(n), m) --> will return m+n

How can I do it in python?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Look up python decorators

Comment: If you're doing functional programming with Python, look into the `functools` built in module. It has some useful stuff.

Comment: I tried what @Stephan described, it works like a charm XD! Will take a look into functools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read about decorators in Python for more on this. For your specific question:

```
def applyIncrease(increaseFn, m):
    return increaseFn(m)

def makeIncrease(n):
    def _innerFn(arg):
        return arg + n
    return _innerFn
```

`applyIncrease` accepts a function and argument, and applies the function to the argument.
`makeIncrease` accepts an argument `n`.

Let's say n=2 for the sake of an example. `makeIncrease(2)` returns a function that takes an argument and adds 2 to it.

Although I began `_innerFn` with an underscore, this is only a convention - the underscore is not required for the decorator to work.

Note also that functions are first class objects in Python, and that `makeIncrease` returns `_innerFn` and not `_innerFn()`. Return functions exactly as you would variables or object references - no parentheses.

Here are your functions in the interpreter. Note that the object reference `wrapped_function` refers to `_innerFn`, i.e. the return value of `makeIncrease(2)`

```
>>> wrapped_function = makeIncrease(2)
>>> wrapped_function
<function _innerFn at 0x100496758>
>>> total = applyIncrease(wrapped_function, 3)
>>> total
5
```

Comment: Thanks you~ I just begin to understand the power of python. Take function as first class citizen is really expressive and intuitive for me to program.

Comment: Guess I need to know more coding conventions to participate open source project, because I do see lots of underscore.... I don't know how to interpret them XD.

Comment: There are some good answers on the underscore on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python). You will see a lot of underscores in open source, especially double underscores, another useful convention. Please accept my answer if it was useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Example:
    def result():
        def nestedResult(a,b):
            multiply = a*b
            return multiply
        return nestedResult  


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        x = result()
        print "multiplication_result:", x(1,10)
```

Comment: Err, no, this does not return a function. It only _calls_ a nested function, and returns the result.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have now corrected the code to not actually call the inner function